# Connecting an IObservableVector<T> to a WinJS ListView

Tags: data-binding, windows-runtime, winjs

We are developing a Metro-style app in C++ and JavaScript. The C++ side provides us with [`IObservableVector<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226052.aspx) instances. The JavaScript side uses the [`WinJS.UI.ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx) control.

List views are normally hooked up to [`WinJS.UI.IListDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211786.aspx) instances. Most typically, one takes a [`WinJS.Binding.List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700774.aspx) and uses its `dataSource` property.

However, it seems very natural to want to hook up an `IObservableVector<T>` to the list view. Is there any way to do this? For example, is there any adapter for turning `IObservableVector<T>`s into `List`s or `IListDataSource`s?

One route we could go down is to write our own custom [`WinJS.UI.IListDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212603.aspx) implementation that hooks up to an `IObservableVector<T>`, then go through the whole game with the poorly-documented [`WinJS.UI.VirtualizedDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701413.aspx) and so on. But, has anyone done this already? It seems like it should be in the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Chris Tavares's helpful, if discouraging, response, I wrote such an adapter:

https://github.com/NobleJS/WinningJS/blob/master/lib/ObservableVectorDataSource.js

It is currently read-only (so you cannot update the data source and expect changes to propagate to the observable vector), but works great in our app.

Answer (score 1):

WinJS 1.0 doesn't support the WinRT change notification interfaces (INotifyPropertyChanged, IObservableVector). If you want to hook them together, you'll need to write an adapter/data source.